# Is this functional series differentiable?

Tags: analysis

Is this functional series differentiable on (-1,1)? If it is could you give the full proof?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n!}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Hint: a power series is differentiable on its open disk of convergence.

Comment: When we throw members of power series away (like x^3,x^4,x^7... that cannot be in original series) we get original series. Also we know that power series is differentiable on (-1,1) and this series without some members is also differentiable on (-1,1). Am I right?